# How to delete rows with a keys based on more values

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I want to delete some rows from a table with SQL. I correctly get the rows to delete from a select statement, but I have trouble for two reason:

1. I can't use aliases for delete instruction
2. the rows have a key based by 3 columns.

I tried with this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE (sec, name, profil) 
IN (
      SELECT mt.sec, mt.name, mt.profil FROM mytable AS mt
      WHERE ...
)
```

This does not work.

I tried with this:

```
WITH rows_to_delete AS (
      SELECT mt.sec AS _sec, mt.name AS _name, mt.profil AS _profil FROM mytable AS mt
      WHERE ...
)
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE sec = rows_to_delete._sec AND name = rows_to_delete._name AND profil = rows_to_delete._profil
```

but columns cannot be bound.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not simply use the same WHERE clause that correctly selects your rows directly in the DELETE statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete command directly with where condition by using "OR"

create table mytable (

sec varchar(50),

name varchar(50),

profil varchar(50)

)

insert into mytable (sec,name,profil) values ('AA','BB','CC')

insert into mytable (sec,name,profil) values ('DD','CC','EE')

insert into mytable (sec,name,profil) values ('FF','GG','KK')

insert into mytable (sec,name,profil) values ('CC','SS','PP')

delete from mytable where sec = 'CC' or name = 'CC' or profil = 'CC'

Try this Link : https://dbfiddle.uk/39C9XMsM